# If verify Google user logged in

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I just developed an application (Jave with GAE) at appspot.com. It allows Google account to authenticate. However, when I sign off from Google account, my GAE cookie (ACSID, SACSID) doesn't synchronize with Google account and it still run as the user id. If I want implement something when I logout Google, I want my app also logout. Is there any Google API for me to refer at?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Users API.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview

UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

Generate a logout link via:
thisUrl = req.getRequestURI();
String logoutURL = userService.createLogoutURL(thisURL);

When the user clicks on the logoutURL, Google will log them out of the application.
It will also log you out of all of your other Google sessions such as GMail, Drive, Calendar etc.

Geoff

Comment: No, this is not the answer I wanted. When I do Google account sign out, my app doesn't sign out. My app always holds a cookie (ACSID/SACSID) which is not the same with google.com cookies (SID/SSID). I want something like an API so that I can verify if SID/SSID are terminated from google.com, my app will force to log out as well.

Comment: @lannyboy What you're describing is single sign-out, and users find it confusing. They don't expect logging out of their Google account to log them out of non-Google services.

Comment: Well, you quote makes sesne if your app is not configured in the Google menu bar. At my case, my app is published as one of the menu item. My users don't care what is OpenID, they just want single sign out when their Gooogle sign out.

Comment: Dan, I'd have to disagree.  What I would find confusing is if I were logged into an application as one Google user, then logged out of Google and logged into a different Google account, but the application I was using still thought I was the original user.  That's not really the point anyway, if OP wants to implement a feature you find confusing, that's their choice.  Do you know of an API call to accomplish this or not?